# How to search fields starting with an external string using awk in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am still very new to bash scripts and I have a small issue.

I wrote a bash script that selected the fields starting with a certain letter from a file ($1), without writing this command for every single letter out there (even though that for doesn't look nice). For simplicity purposes, I put here only the non-functionable part of my code, so I wouldn't bother you with the rest of my task, which I was able to do.

So this is it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -f $1
then
        for F in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
        do
                echo `cat $1 | awk -v aux="$F" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i ~ "aux*" )print $i;}END{}'`
        done
else
        echo $1 is not a file
fi
```

I am perfectly aware of what goes wrong(when I compare, because it shows fields that have au and x 0 or more times), but I tried a multitude of fixes and none of them worked, so this is only one of them. I tried doing a regex, also showing that the character I'm looking for is at the beginning, but it had a similar effect to this.

Do you have any idea how can I reach the result I wanted without modifying the structure of this code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ```($i ~ ("^" aux))```

Comment: First copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then [edit] your question to show the updated script and a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice one!

Comment: Don't just take what @vgersh99 said as the "fix" because your script has more serious issues that neither shellcheck nor that tweak can help you with. If you'd like help doing what you're trying to do the right way then do what I suggested in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023041/how-to-search-fields-starting-with-an-external-string-using-awk-in-bash-script#comment118470781_67023041) so we can help you.

Comment: I will do that to improve the full code. Thank you!